# Select two pandas columns that have the same digit in the column name

Tags: python, pandas

I am cleaning up some data and the raw dataset has entries as `['Field1.1', 'Field2.1', 'Field1.2', 'Field2.2']`. For the dataset, either `'Field1' XOR 'Field2'` will have a non-empty string. I'd like to create a single field `'Field.1'` that will extract the non-empty string from `'Field1.1'` XOR `'Field2.1'` and place it in `'Field.1'`. Similarly, I'd like to do this for `'Field1.2'` and `'Field2.2'` as `'Field.2'`.

I am not sure how to select matching fields, i.e. 'X.1' with 'Y.1' and 'X.2' with 'Y.2', in order to do this.

---

My logic is that once I can select the correct pairs I can simply use a concat statement to add them and thereby extract the non-empty string for later use. If this logic is incorrect or there is a better way that does not rely on extracting the non-empty string in this way to concatenate them then please let me know.

---

If the logic is sound, please explain how might do this extraction given the indexing problem.

---

To be clearer, I want to go from:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'field1.1': ['string1',''], 'field2.1':['','string2'],
                   'field1.2': ['string3',''], 'field2.2':['','string4']})

df

Out[1]: 
  field1.1 field2.1 field1.2 field2.2
0  string1           string2         
1           string3           string4
```

to:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'field.1': ['string1','string3'], 'field.2':['string2','string4']})

df2

Out[2]: 
   field.1  field.2
0  string1  string2
1  string3  string4
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: Or at least, provide a sample data with expected output. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wide_to_long`, `bfill`, and then `pivot` back:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df.where(df.ne('')).reset_index(), 
                 stubnames=['Field1','Field2'],
                 i='index', 
                 j='group', 
                 sep='.')
 .bfill(1)
 .reset_index()
 .pivot(values='Field1',index='index',columns='group')
)
```

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a','','b',''],
    ['c','','','d'],
    ['','e','','f'],
    ['','g','h','']],
    columns=['Field1.1', 'Field2.1', 'Field1.2', 'Field2.2'])

group  1  2
index      
0      a  b
1      c  d
2      e  f
3      g  h
```